# Scifi TV Show which had the common "Aliens invading the world" sort of setting?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I am looking for this really hard to find scifi TV show which had the common theme of aliens invading the world. It was not an animation, I remember vaguely watching it when I was little (so perhaps 2006-2008)? All I remember at the time this scifi series came out was that it was being promoted by some energy drink. V perhaps? I remember seeing the first episode and a TV promo of it on some NZ broadcasting channel. Chanel 7 perhaps? I remember it like this....

In the TV promo there were giant, weird looking spaceships and there was a main mother ship that came to Earth and appeared in places such as Egypt, New York, perhaps Manhattan etc. In this TV promo I vaguely remember a woman (perhaps black) who appeared on this giant screen on these ships that landed all over the world and she says "we come in peace" and mumbled some speech to the world about world peace, blah, blah, blah that I cannot remember. Moving to the episode (perhaps it was from episode 1).

I cannot be too sure but I remember that this woman who spoke on these giant screens was actually planning something sinister. I remember a particular scene where there is a pool of water in this ship, in which there was a human or a soldier, and she places her hands on his head or  around/on his face. I am sure something horrible happened to this guy and I believe she was in some sort of alien cult and was brainwashing humans.

I believe there was this baby that this woman was trying to obtain. For what reasons, I cannot remember but I believe this baby might have been half alien/half human and had incredible power that these aliens wanted? I seriously cannot remember that much. I remember the mother was trying to escape from them perhaps through some forest or something? Very unclear on this scene.

I also believe this woman/alien was raising some sort of army in secret and had her own agendas (quite the opposite from her "come in peace" speech).

I have tried searching and searching and searching using generic key terms related to what I am asking but have had no luck in finding something or at least a match.

Comment: Its V --- http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1307824/

Comment: @Tasos- Oh, Lol. I must have got confused. xD

Comment: I think I just mis-remembered.

Comment: I'm not sure one could get away with calling Morena Baccarin "a negro" (wtf?!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Tasos says, this sounds like the second re-make of [*V*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1307824/), though it is a reasonably common trope, and I wouldn't be surprised if it was something else. I don't remember the energy-drink V sponsoring it, but that might have been something I've simply forgotten or that only took place in New Zealand, the bastard step-child of the *Terra Nullus* I call home. Everything else you mention happens during the first two seasons of the show; I stopped watching mid-way through Season 2, so no idea if it went further. I doubt it, since the Brazilian actress playing Ana went on to do *Homeland*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still pretty sure I remember a promo for it though. Lol, and I was pretty surprised that the title I was looking for was V. Thanks. :)